# エンドポイントとは何か

Tags: プログラミング言語

プログラミングにおいて、エンドポイントとはどういう意味なのでしょうか？

Comment: 場合によって意味が異なる可能性はあるので、どういう場合に使われていた言葉なのかをもっと限定して下さいませんか？　質問文の下の「編集」から追記が可能です。

Comment: @nekketsuuu  エンドポイントという表現を見たのは、「このソースコードの中でどこがエンドポイントだろうか？」という記載です。

Comment: どの言語の、どういう場面（通信ネットワーク関連、回路関連、など）でしょうか。

Comment: @nekketsuuu  Pythonの、ユーザー認証を行う時です。ちなみに、エンドポイントは物によりそんなに意味が変わるのでしょうか？どういうケースの場合はこの意味、のようにそれぞれに対して教えていただけると嬉しいです

Answer (score 5, accepted):

一般的な英語の話として、「エンドポイント (endpoint)」とは「端点」という意味です。ここから転じて、通信ネットワークでの専門用語として、ネットワーク末端の端末（多くはクライアントのこと）を「エンドポイント」と呼びます。

同様の発想で、ソフトウェア分野では、API にアクセスするための URI そのものや、公開されている機能を使うための識別子を「エンドポイント」と呼ぶことがあります。

他にも、今回の例に関係あるか分かりませんが、認証や認可の文脈だと [OAuth 2.0 のドキュメント](https://openid-foundation-japan.github.io/rfc6749.ja.html#anchor16)に「エンドポイント」という言葉が出てきます。

#### 参考

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endpoint
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_API#Endpoints
- [エンドポイントとは](http://e-words.jp/w/%E3%82%A8%E3%83%B3%E3%83%89%E3%83%9D%E3%82%A4%E3%83%B3%E3%83%88.html) -- e-words.jp